# Why does desktop stay visible when Explorer process exits?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, desktop

I've always wondered what subsystem in Windows is responsible for displaying desktop background image and icons even when the Windows Explorer process is not working.

The common scenario is that some extension or external drive malfunctioned and the Explorer process died. While a new instance is being started, the desktop icons and background are still visible and you can do things with them as usual. The only difference is that all windows are gone and the taskbar is missing. You can also manually kill Explorer process to see what I mean, but you  better know how to restore it before doing it.

What process (or subsystem) keeps  desktop image and icons alive while Explorer process is down?

Comment: Also don't try suspending `dwm.exe`. Srsly it's bad.